# select for reading after a fork

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, multiprocessing

how is select for reading being handled on Linux systems in case the process was forked after opening a udp socket?
Especially - is it possible that in this kind of program:

```
so = open socket
fork
for(;;) {
  select() for reading on socket so
  recv from so
}
```

two packets will wake up only one of the processes (in case they arrive before the waiting process is notified / exits select) and the second one of those packets will not be received?

Or can I assume that for UDP, every packet will always wake up a process or leave the flag set?

Answer (score 1):

Each processes, the parent and child, has a fie descriptor for the same socket. The per file descriptor attributes are independent (e.g. blocking, being able to close the socket).

In your scenario it is indeed feasible legal for one of the processes, for example to be waken and read the data from the socket before the other one getting into select.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not actually affected by the `fork()` at all.

`select()` returns if one of the file descriptors in the read set is readable.  If you don't read from it and call `select()` again, it will still be readable.  It will be remain readable until there is no more data to read from it.

In other words, `select()` is level-triggered, not edge-triggered.